# In Postgres SQL how to convert values as range and get the range with maximum records

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Having a table of students with their name and age as follows how to convert values of age as a range of

- 7-9
- 9-11
- 11-13
- 13-15
- 15-17
- 17-19

and get the age range with maximum students

Creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  age FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

Inserting values:

```
INSERT INTO students
VALUES
(1, 'Ryan', 12),
(2, 'Joanna', 12.5),
(3, 'James', 11),
(4, 'Karen', 10),
(5, 'Holmes', 11.2),
(6, 'Garry', 12.1),
(7, 'Justin', 14.5),
(8, 'Emma', 15),
(9, 'Andy', 10),
(10, 'Claren', 9.5),
(11, 'Dennis', 9),
(12, 'Henna', 16),
(13, 'Iwanka', 15.4),
(14, 'June', 8.1),
(15, 'Kamila', 7.5),
(16, 'Lance', 17);
```

Expected Output should be range with max count of records:

```
Range | Count 
10-12 | 5
```

Comment: Providing sample data is good but What's your expected result?

Comment: You can't store the value `7.5` into an `integer` column. It will be rounded to `8`

Comment: Your age column is an int but your insert value has floating point.

Comment: Updated. There could be tiny glitches, please ignore those, the result that I want is explained above the create table and insert queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use an aggregate function with `CASE WHEN` expression for your logic, then use `ORDER BY COUNT DESC` to get max count of records

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN '7-9'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN '10-12'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 13 AND 15 THEN '13-15'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 15 AND 17 THEN '15-17'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 17 AND 19 THEN '17-19' END) as range,
      COUNT(*) cnt
FROM students
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN '7-9'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN '10-12'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 13 AND 15 THEN '13-15'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 15 AND 17 THEN '15-17'
           WHEN age BETWEEN 17 AND 19 THEN '17-19' END
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

**edit**

if you range number has a logic and you want a generic range solution

you can try to use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) generate a range number with your range logic then do outer join.

For your sample data I would use `generate_series(7,17,2)` create a range number which you expect the calutaion start and end number

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.startnum,'-',t1.endnum) as range,
      COUNT(*) cnt
FROM students s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT v startnum,v+2 endnum
    FROM generate_series(7,17,2) v 
  ) t1 ON s.age BETWEEN t1.startnum AND t1.endnum
GROUP BY CONCAT(t1.startnum,'-',t1.endnum)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8d1d71d5ec26e6158beb17031cf71940)

Comment: The data in question is dummy data. It is not like that is all the data I have. I want a generic range solution that can be implemented on any amount of data or even other fields

Comment: Is there any logic in your range column? if yes please explain that

Comment: Logic is interval, for example size of 3

Comment: but your range data might make two logic of `10-12` and `13-15` are not continue but 
are `13-15` `15-17`

Comment: that is my mistake. fixing that in question

Comment: @VinitKhandelwal I had edit my answer you can try that

Answer (score 2):

--construct numrange table.

```
CREATE TABLE age_range (
    id serial,
    agerange numrange
);

INSERT INTO age_range (agerange)
    VALUES ('[7,9]'), ('[10,12]'), ('[13,15]'), ('[15,17]'), ('[17,19]');
```

--cte with window function.

```
  WITH a AS (
    SELECT
        age,
        name,
        agerange
    FROM
        students s,
        age_range b
    WHERE
        age <@ agerange IS TRUE
)
SELECT
    *,
    count(agerange) OVER (PARTITION BY agerange)
FROM
    a
ORDER BY
    agerange,
    name;
```

Comment: there is no float range type, I use numrange. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: Instead of a separate table, use a `VALUES` clause or `unnest(ARRAY[...])`. A bit of careful formatting would make your answer that much more readable. It's keeping me from upvoting...

Comment: @Patrick  You are right. Thanks for the tip, updated the format. first time use pgformatter. I hope it's fine.